# constructing a graph from streaming data using spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark. I need to construct a co-occurrence graph(In a tweet -words will become nodes and the if the words are from same tweet we add an edge between them) from streaming data like twitter tweets. Can we use spark streaming to construct a live co-occurrence twitter graph. Is spark streaming is meant for this use case?. I am not sure whether it can be done using spark streaming . If not what are the alternatives?

Comment: can any body answer this please...

Comment: I guess spark graphX uses google pregel computation model which is intended for batch. Flink Gelly also follows the same approach. I have been trying to find the library my self which can handle Streaming data graph processing. So far I found one experimental single pass graph streaming library, which works on top of Flink. https://github.com/vasia/gelly-streaming.git. Also let me know if you have any findings your self. :)

Answer (score 1):

the co-occurrence frequency can be seen as a graph or an adjacency matrix, but this is a large sparse histogram (frequency count) in the product space of your word list.  most likely you wish to detect a moving window correlation so should design a sketch data structure to track unusual increase or decrease in rate of occurrence in the stream. e.g. counting bloom filter or count min sketch applied to every word-pair - see http://twitter.github.io/algebird/#com.twitter.algebird.CMSCounting

Comment: sorry, I couldn't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate on the things you said?